# Lazy.get ANR triggered by a deadlock involving the main thread at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(FirebaseApp.java:594)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

In Firebase Crashlytics, I have observed loads of ANR triggered by a deadlock involving the main thread.

In The Application, I have implemented the below code to get the Firebase User

```
object FirebaseAuthAsFlow {
private val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

fun getFirebaseUser(): Flow<FirebaseUser?> =
    callbackFlow {
        val authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener {
            trySendBlocking(it.currentUser)
        }
        firebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
        awaitClose { firebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener) }
    }
```

}

and from the Application class, I am calling the above code:

```
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            FirebaseAuthAsFlow.getFirebaseUser().collect{
               it?.let {
                   Log.d("userId","${it.uid}")
            }
        }
}
 }
```

Below are the logs from the Firebase console:

```
main (blocked):tid=1 systid=1347 | waiting to lock <0x0967c3b7> (s9.p) held by thread 29
       at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:50)
       at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.doInitializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:291)
       at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(ComponentRuntime.java:281)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(FirebaseApp.java:594)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.access$400(FirebaseApp.java:90)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp$UserUnlockReceiver.onReceive(FirebaseApp.java:659)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1580)
       at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(lambda)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7664)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
efaultDispatcher-worker-2 (blocked):tid=29 systid=1487 | waiting to lock <0x055a4724> (java.lang.Object) held by thread 1
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:201)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzbg.zzf(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:21)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzbg.zza(zzbg.java:7)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:14)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzv.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:1)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthRegistrar.lambda$getComponents$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:3)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.zzv.create(zzv.java)
       at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$discoverComponents$0(ComponentRuntime.java:132)
       at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:53)
       at com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer.get(AbstractComponentContainer.java:27)
       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.get(FirebaseApp.java:338)
       at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:2)
       at com.mypackage.FirebaseAuthAsFlow.<clinit>(FirebaseAuthAsFlow.kt:12)
       at com.mypackage.MyApplication$onCreate$2.invokeSuspend(MyApplication.kt:73)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.ScopeCoroutine.afterResume(Scopes.kt:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.resumeWith(AbstractCoroutine.kt:102)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:749)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
```

Comment: Looks like an internal bug in Firebase since it is deadlocking with itself. Maybe you can avoid the problem by using `Dispatchers.Main` for the coroutine in the Application that collects the flow. It's not doing any blocking work in the flow or collect block anyway so that should be fine. Alternatively, you could simply declare the `FirebaseAuthAsFlow` object reference in your `Application.onCreate` function before you do anything else so the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance()` call is guaranteed to happen on the main thread during object instantiation.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to call Firebase APIs on the `Application` class. Could you call it on your launcher Activity instead?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks,  if I understand correctly, You are saying I need to call FirebaseAuth.getInstance() in a Main Thread. Right Now I am calling  override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            FirebaseAuthAsFlow.getFirebaseUser().collect{
               it?.let {
                   Log.d("userId","${it.uid}")
            }
        }
}
}